# Match() on object array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I have an object array with multiple variables.

```js
let Books = [];

class Book {
  constructor(docID, title, author, edition, publication, year) {
    this.docID = docID;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.publication = publication;
    this.year = year;
    this.edition = edition;
  }
}

//Example
ISBN = "978-1-56619-909-4";
title = "Book title";
authors = ["author1", "author2"];
edition = 1;
publication = "Book publisher";
year = 2021;

temp = new Book(ISBN, title, authors, edition, publication, year);
Books.push(temp);
```

I have a search bar and I need to search and filter certain variables in the array. For example, I need to search the title variable for matches and filter only those that match the input. I use match() to look for matches.

```js
let searchText = "title"; //Given by user
if (searchText != "") {
  let searchQuery = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
  filtered_results = Books.match(searchQuery);
} else {
  filtered_results = Books;
}
```

However, I get an error saying match() is not available for Books (because it's not a string). If I use it on my string variable it works (Books[1].title.match()). In that case, I need to use a loop and look for a match in every iteration.

Is there an efficient way of doing this without a loop? Because I need to check for matches in author and publication if the title doesn't match. I don't think looping through the object every time is an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: what is expected output ?

Comment: I need to filter the Books object which matches the search criteria (either title, author or publication)

Comment: `match` works on string. `Books` is an array

Comment: I know. Using it on a string works. But it's not an efficient way as I mentioned. I just want to know if there is a similar function or workaround that lets me look for matches directly on the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

To filter through your array of books,

```
let searchQuery = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
filtered_results = Books.filter(book => searchQuery.test(book.title));
```

Here, we are checking through every book in the `Books` array, then using the `RegExp` to [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) if the book title is a match

You also don't need the `if` conditional, the `RegExp` will return all the books in the case of an empty string.